# SpringBoot Webflux: save POJO in different tables using reactive repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Small question regarding how to save a Mono into a particular reactive table please.

I have a very simple piece of code:

```
    @Override
    public Mono<MyPojo> question() {
        return myPojoRepository.insert(someService.getMonoMyPojo());
    }
```

where MyPojo is just a POJO with a state represented by a String:

```
@Table
public class MyPojo {

    private String  state;
```

The service just computes a MyPojo, with a state "good" or "bad"

and finally, any reactive repository for saving the MyPojo.

```
@Repository
public interface MyPojoRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<MyPojo, String> {

}
```

My reactive database have three tables, table 1, mygoodpojo table, table two, mybadpojo table, and mypojo table.

What I would like to achieve, is depending on the state of MyPojo the service computes, to save in the good or bad table.

As of now, with the repository as

```
public interface MyPojoRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<MyPojo, String> {
```

It is saving all MyPojo, regardless of the state, into the mypojotable.

May I ask how to perform the use case where the good MyPojo is saved inside mygoodpojo, and the bad MyPojo saved inside mybadpojo please?

In a non reactive world, I would have written something like:

```
if (myPojo.getState().equals("good")) {
    Statement statement = Insert into mygoodpojo [...];
    } else {
Statement statement = Insert into mybadpojo [...];
}
```

But I am having a hard time doing the same with this reactive stack.

Any help please?

Thank you!

Comment: while this is not the answer you are looking but it is a reference of what you might actually implement https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-jpa-with-hibernate-inheritance-mapping/

Comment: Very interesting article, something more Webflux would be great!

Comment: is there a reason why you can't add your conditional logic inside a `flatMap` operator?

Comment: I think that is worth trying! But I do not have any flatMap operator, just a ```return myPojoRepository.insert(someService.getMonoMyPojo());```